# JSON data is not passing to the controller action and gives POST 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have file called pizzas.json. I have read the data from this file but i make a jquery ajax call it doesn't pass to to the controller and gives "POST 500 internal server error". look my my code in images:

**View**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getToppingsList() {
       $.getJSON("../pizzas.json", passDataToController);
       }


        //var newdata = JSON.parse(data);
        //alert(requestData);
        function passDataToController(json) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetToppingsList","ToppingsList")",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Get Toppings List" id="Render JSON" onclick="getToppingsList()" />
```

**Controller**

```
public class ToppingsListController : Controller
{                

    // GET: ToppingsList
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetToppingsList(List<string> ToppingsListArgument)
    {
        //ar name = "waqas";
        return Json(ToppingsListArgument);
    }
}
```

Look in image for error:
[image]

Comment: don't `JSON.stringify()` your data - jQuery does that for you. Change: `data: JSON.stringify(json),` to `data: json,`

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks but now I am receiving null value in action argument

Comment: @WaqasQureshi - then you should [edit] you question and rewrite it to demonstrate the new problem.

Comment: your parameter type is wrong

Comment: @WaqasQureshi for new problem change List<string> ToppingsListArgument to string  ToppingsListArgument

Answer (score 0):

try check if JSON contain any data or not 
try this code

```
function passDataToController(json) {
        var ToppingsListArgument = JSON.stringify(json) ; 
   if(ToppingsListArgument !=null && ToppingsListArgument!=undfind)
       {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetToppingsList","ToppingsList")",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: ToppingsListArgument,
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
        }
```